# Errors in the implementation of CREATOR Field of the Parcelable interface

Tags: java, android

If I implement a Parcelable interface in a class that is declared in MainActivity, I have problems with CREATOR field.

```
public static final Creator<CommunicatorServiceImpl> CREATOR = new Creator<CommunicatorServiceImpl>() {
        @Override
        public CommunicatorServiceImpl createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CommunicatorServiceImpl(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CommunicatorServiceImpl[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CommunicatorServiceImpl[size];
        }
    };
```

1.Error "Inner class cannot have static declaration"

2.In this place

```
 return new CommunicatorServiceImpl(in);
```

i have error "MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context"

I need to implement Parcelable interface in this class, because I need to transfer an object of this class to the service. How can I sove this problems?

Code of the MainActivity: http://www.note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/6e53f3deeeb039227c83eab5746f341a?page=1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the Constructor `CommunicatorServiceImpl(in)` aswell as the code from MainActivity where you try to call your Code

Comment: Do not attempt transfer your Activity object to a service. This is a really bad practice. If you need to communicate from within your service back to the Activity there are better solutions: BroadcastRecivers, binding activity are some of them.

Comment: Сode of the MainActivity: http://www.note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/6e53f3deeeb039227c83eab5746f341a?page=1